# Tunnel using PuTTY - equivalent for ssh command?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tunnel

I am trying to connect to a remote server, based on the instructions given on this page:
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#ssh-tunnels

It suggests to create a tunnel from my local machine to my server using the command:

```
ssh -NfL localhost:5006:localhost:5006 user@remote.host
```

However my local machine is Windows - being a beginner programmer I have trouble figuring out how to reproduce the above mention command, but with PuTTY.

Could anyone help me out with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do this directly with Putty command line:

```
putty.exe -L 5006:<remote_host>:5006 -P 22 -l <user> -pw <pwd>
```

where

- `<remote_host>` is your remote host (running the server listening on port 5006)
- `<user>`/`<pwd>` are the credentials to access via SSH to `<remote_host>`

assuming SSH port is 22

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY comes with console client Plink.

Plink has the same command-line syntax as OpenSSH `ssh` except:

- for the `-f` switch, which does not have an equivalent in Windows.
- and you cannot combine multiple switches after one dash - so instead of `-NL ...`, you have to use `-N -L ...`.

So, you can use:

```
plink.exe -N -L localhost:5006:localhost:5006 user@remote.host
```

Reference: [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)

---

Alternatively you can setup the tunnel in PuTTY GUI.

See [How to create SSH tunnel using PuTTY in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4974131/850848#29168936)