# SSH private key to access remote GUI

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, putty, ssh-keys

I am new to SSH and i want to log into a remote server using private key i generated using puttygen. I have already sent my public key to the server admin. I was instructed to execute following command in order to access GUI.

```
ssh -i <your private key> -D <your forwarding port for the GUI> james.alt@con.pod7.utvr
```

Can anyone explain what to put for my private key? Is it the file location in my local PC or some place in the remote server ? and what port number to use to access a remote GUI ?

Im using a windows machine with putty. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct that your private key is stored on your local computer and passed to the server—so the “<your private key>” portion would be the path to the file. Here is the SSH man page for some more guidance: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh.    Edit: check the man page for information on the D flag.

Comment: Though if you want to use PuTTY, you have to add the private key path to your PuTTY configuration. The above `ssh` commandline is not relevant for PuTTY, which is GUI terminal client.

Comment: I have already added the private key path to the putty configuration.So i can connect to the server CLI through putty. But i need to access the GUI. Any advice on that ?

Comment: What GUI? Please be more specific. Do you mean the server desktop? Or some X Windows application? Or (based on your `ssh` command), do you want to forward some port that will then be used by some GUI application to access the server?

Comment: Forwarding a port for a GUI to access the server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tunnel using PuTTY - equivalent for ssh command?](https://superuser.com/questions/1263587/tunnel-using-putty-equivalent-for-ssh-command)