# Automatic connection to remote server via PuTTY and ports contained in .json file

Tags: ssh, putty, remote-access

I connect myself to this remote cluster via PuTTY client. This works when I have written scripts to run or I'm running something in `bash`. But recently I figured out how to connect Spyder IDE to this remote cluster, so I can write Python code "locally", but execute it on the cluster.
To first connect my Spyder IDE to my remote cluster, I log in to my cluster server and start my custom bash alias via code:

```
'cd $HOME/spyder_kernel; module load conda; source activate py38; python -m spyder_kernels.console - matplotlib=’inline’    --ip=127.0.0.1 -f=./remotemachine.json'
```

In a nutshell, I change directory to where my spyder kernel is, I load conda, and I load my virtual environment named `py38` in which I have `spyder-kernels` module installed. This creates `remotemachine.json`. I copy this file to my local environment.

Next step is opening another PuTTY configuration, and under `Connection`-`SSH`-`Tunnels` I need to add all ports written in `.json` file. I've provided example (numbers are fudged) how this looks like below.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXZZs.jpg)

I have to manually input each and every port under Source port and Destination. I thought about saving settings, but numbers for ports change.

Is there a way to load the `.json` file in PuTTY, and have the Forwarded ports auto complete?

Comment: PuTTY accepts [`-L` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-portfwd), which can be used to forward ports. So transform your json to equivalent `-L` parameters. See also [Tunnel using PuTTY - equivalent for ssh command?](https://superuser.com/q/1263587/213663)

Comment: Can I add multiple parameters, as I have multiple ports?

Comment: Also, how would I pass -L parameter for one port to have it identical in PuTTY GUI?

Comment: I believe you can use `-L` multiple times. I do not understand your second question.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Spyder kernels automatically opened the tunnels so I had no need to open then in a command line via plink. But yeah, L switched worked. Thanks for help anyway!